# Reactive Spring Integration equivalent to Project Reactor .doOnNext()

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-integration, project-reactor

As a user of Project Reactor that also wants to use Spring Integration, I'd like to perform the following operation, that will work in such way that:

```java
flux.buffer(duration)
    .doOnNext(bulkWriteToCockroach())
    .doOnNext(bulkWriteToPulsar());
```

In the beginning, I thought the solution is to do stuff like the following *wrong* code:

```java
IntegrationFlow.from(myflow)
    .aggregate(myTimeBasedAggregation())
    .handle(bulkWriteToCockroach())
    .handle(bulkWriteToPulsar());
```

Of course, it wouldn't work due to `outputChannel` issues. I would like to know how can I perform operations one after another (e.g. don't continue to the Pulsar writes until the CockroachDB writes are completed, and stop the flow for these messages if the first operation fails).

I'm thinking of using [the Spring Integration transactions support](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-integration-transaction) but I'm afraid of its usage with Reactor.

I've also seen that there is something called [`gateway()`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/gateway.html#reactor-mono), but I've couldn't manage to find a usable example of a JavaDSL based usage of it.

Answer (score 0):

To send the same message to different endpoints, you should consider to use a `PublishSubscribeChannel`, which really don't send to the next subscriber if the previous fails.

See its JavaDocs:

```
/**
 * Specify whether failures for one or more of the handlers should be
 * ignored. By default this is false meaning that an Exception
 * will be thrown whenever a handler fails. To override this and suppress
 * Exceptions, set the value to true.
 * @param ignoreFailures true if failures should be ignored.
 */
public void setIgnoreFailures(boolean ignoreFailures) {
```

With Java DSL you should look into a:

```
/**
 * The {@link org.springframework.integration.channel.PublishSubscribeChannel} {@link #channel}
 * method specific implementation to allow the use of the 'subflow' subscriber capability.
 * @param publishSubscribeChannelConfigurer the {@link Consumer} to specify
 * {@link PublishSubscribeSpec} options including 'subflow' definition.
 * @return the current {@link BaseIntegrationFlowDefinition}.
 */
public B publishSubscribeChannel(Consumer<PublishSubscribeSpec> publishSubscribeChannelConfigurer) {
```

The sample for which could look like this:

```
                .publishSubscribeChannel(s -> s
                        .subscribe(f -> f
                                .handle(bulkWriteToCockroach()))
                        .subscribe(f -> f
                                .handle(bulkWriteToPulsar())));
```

See more in the docs: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/dsl.html#java-dsl-subflows

**UPDATE**

The `gateway()` is explained here in docs: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/dsl.html#java-dsl-gateway